# Magento 2 - Best SMS notification module?

Tags: magento, sms

I need to send sms to my customers on Magento 2.x when the state of their order change.
For example, when the order is accept, send, delivered.

But there is a LOT of module for this purpose, so which one do you advise me ?

( I don't care about the price )

I found them :

[From MageComp](https://magecomp.com/magento-2-sms-notification.html)

[Twilio](https://codecanyon.net/item/magento-2-twilio-sms-notification/17414386)

[From makarovsoft](https://ecommerce.makarovsoft.com/sms-to-customers-magento-2.html)

[From SpringEdge](https://www.springedge.com/magento-sms-extension-module-free.html)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with Mage Comp they are good in sms or also with Spring edge.
You can also create your own SMS module with various magento event

Thanks